# how to handle images upload when creating a post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image

I am building a little social site. Currently i am having issues with the image upload section. What i want is the user to be able to optionally upload an image while creating a post. Right now i am loading the images to the browser as `base64` strings then when the user hits post, i use `ajax` to send the post and the image string to the server, then convert the image back to `jpeg`. What i implemented is very  identical to this https://medium.freecodecamp.org/vue-js-introduction-for-people-who-know-just-enough-jquery-to-get-by-eab5aa193d77

It seemed to be working well for small images but when large images are "**attached** " to the browser for submission to the server, i begin to notice a drastic drop in the browser performance ( due the large image size). okay so my question is what better options do i have to implement this functionality.

If i want to go with the option of uploading the image to the server through ajax immediately the user adds it, how do i handle situations when the user did not complete writing the post and submit it ? I am using laravel for the backend

Comment: You can try to resize the image before they are rendered on the browser so that it won't affect performance. However if want to send the image before you could create/submit the post - you might need to send some kind of identification element that you can later relate the image with this post. Of course, this also means you'll have to periodically delete orphan images without any post for images where the user didn't complete creating the post.

Comment: You could initially show the image as base64 string like you are currently. but keep the image in a html file upload field. Once he hits the "post" button just serialize all the form data and send it as a multipart POST via your ajax request.

Comment: For a start, look at doing a proper PHP file upload - there are numerous tutorials on this. Flag in a database when the upload begins. Update this flag upon successful upload. In terms of "orphan" uploads, if you're using PHP's normal upload facilities they begin by going into a temp directory, which gets cleaned up. You could also use a cron job to go through your database and delete anything which is in the database flagged as "upload has started, but never completed", after a set time.